# How can I call javascript function, having ajax call from Java using ScriptEngine?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I am getting following exception:
jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined

But how can I have jquery available for the javascript function?

Following is my code:
Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/callAjax"}, method={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public String callAjax(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws Exception {
        logger.info("request came to /callAjax");

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        InputStream fis = AjaxRequestController.class.getResourceAsStream("path to my js file");
        InputStreamReader fileReader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        engine.eval(fileReader);
        Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
        inv.invokeFunction("ajaxMethod");
        return null;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
function ajaxMethod(){
    $.ajax({ 
        dataType: "json",
           type: "GET", 
           cache: false,
           url: 'myurl',
           success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't!

Although `nashorn` (java 8's javascript engine) runs `ECMAscript` compliant javascript, but implicit objects from browsers like `window`, `document` are still not available. JQuery or `$`, attaches it to `window` object hence it will not work. Use other ways for making async http requests in java.